# OSGi bundle build issue in Gradle

Tags: gradle, blueprint-osgi

I have a simple use case of building an OSGi bundle using Gradle build tool. The build is successful if there are java files present in the build path, but it fails otherwise.

I am using 'osgi' plugin inside the gradle script and trying to build without any java files. The build always fails with following error:

**Could not copy MANIFEST.MF to**

I am sure there must be some way to do it in Gradle but not able to fine. Any idea what can be done to resolve this depending on your experience.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this today as well, and @Peter's fix didn't work for me (I hadn't applied the java plugin in the first place...). However, after hours of Googling I did find [this thread](http://gradle.1045684.n5.nabble.com/osgiManifest-does-not-work-outside-of-default-jar-task-td2740138.html), which helped me find the problem.

Basically, it seems that the error occurs ([as Peter stated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16877368/38055)) when no class files are found in the jar - my guess is because the plugin then cannot scan the classes for package names on which to base all the `Import` and `Export` information.

My solution was to add the following to the manifest specification:

```
classesDir = theSourceSet.output.classesDir
classpath = theSourceSet.runtimeClasspath
```

In my actual build code, I loop over all source sets to create `jar` tasks for them, so then it looks like this:

```
sourceSets.each { ss -> 
    assemble.dependsOn task("jar${ss.name.capitalize()}", type: Jar, dependsOn: ss.getCompileTaskName('Java')) {
        from ss.output
        into 'classes'

        manifest = osgiManifest {
            classesDir = ss.output.classesDir
            classpath = ss.runtimeClasspath
            // Other properties, like name and symbolicName, also set based on 
            // the name of the source set
        }

        baseName = ss.name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Running with `--stacktrace` indicates that the `osgi` plugin doesn't deal correctly with the case where both the `osgi` and the `java` plugins are applied, but no Java code is present. Removing the `java` plugin should solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue also when java code was present. 
Adding these two lines to the osgiManifest closure fixed the problem:

```
classesDir = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
```

-- erik